# Using multiple fields with ComplexPhraseQueryParser in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

I am currently using Lucene's [MultiFieldQueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/MultiFieldQueryParser.html) to search the same query across multiple fields (ie a search for "value" produces `field1:value field2:value field3:value`). However, this uses the standard [QueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/QueryParser.html) which does [not support wild card searches within phrases](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/queryparsersyntax.html#Wildcard%20Searches) (ie "test phrase*"). So I am trying to use the [ComplexPhraseQueryPhrase](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/contrib-misc/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/complexPhrase/ComplexPhraseQueryParser.html) from the contrib/misc package, which does support that. However, that only allows you to search one field at a time, much like QueryParser.

So I have been trying to combine the two, making a MultiFieldComplexPhraseQueryParser, but I have not had any success yet. Has anyone done anything like this or have any suggestions on how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was actually successful from the get go with MultiFieldQueryParser (Lucene 3.0.3):

```
public class MultiFieldQueryParserTests {
    @Test
    public void testMultiFieldQueryParser() throws Exception {
        MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, 
                                                                        new String[] { "field1", "field2", "field3" },
                                                                        new WhitespaceAnalyzer());
        Query q = parser.parse("test phrase*");
        System.out.println("query " + q);
        q = parser.parse("\"test phrase*\"");
        System.out.println("query " + q);
    }
}
```

Which results in:

```
query (field1:test field2:test field3:test) (field1:phrase* field2:phrase* field3:phrase*)
query field1:"test phrase*" field2:"test phrase*" field3:"test phrase*"
```

Or did I miss something here?

Comment: I think the difference is the analyzer. I don't have it in front of me right now, but I'm pretty sure I'm using the StandardAnalyzer.

Comment: The analyzer shouldn't really make a difference I think. The QueryParser is going to make wildcard queries before passing the tokens to the analyzer, as far as I can tell.